# How to make the null or 0 stored 0, not infinity in elasticsearch

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, sort

1. I have define new eav attribute(`Test_decimal`) with '`decimal`' type. The `Test_decimal` can sort in PLP and SRP.
2. Added value to Test_decimal attribute for some products
3. Run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

But when I searched in the elasticsearch, I have found there are have more value is `Infinity`, the details as follow:

```
"sort": [
     "Infinity"
     ]
```

How to make the null or 0 stored 0, not infinity in elasticsearch

Thanks.